# How to add html(ejs) view to node.js express

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I have a set of html, css, jquery files which is only available of providing a view.

I'm trying to add these set of files to a node.js express(ejs/css) project. I've copied the entire file below the views folder, and made it route to the ejs(I changed the html file's extension to html->ejs) file. The page opens, but it fails to load images, and the css, jquery doesn't seem to show any effect at all.

Putting the image files below the "public" folder, and changing image source url made the image to show properly, but I'm really not sure about the jquery and the css file. And, as a matter of fact, changing every url in this file seems to be a nonsense. Is there any other 'smarter' way to do this work?

Comment: a easy solution may be - store server relative path in an json variable and pass that with ejs.render or ejs.renderfile and prefix your css/js path with <%= yourvar%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the browser, JavaScript (jQuery) files and CSS files are the same as images – separate, static resources to load additionally to the HTML. So you will have to serve them as static files as well, just like your images.

If you don't want to change the URLs, you would have to change the [express configuration](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) to serve the static files at the desired URL.

If you choose to change the URLs, an editor that supports search/replace across multiple files (such as [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/)) will be helpful.